# Will stream().limit() optimize execution if total size of list is less than limit?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, limit

If the `limit` value is greater than the size of the `list`, will java optimize and not execute this code?

```
List<Long> someList = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L);
int limit = 5;
List<Long> limitedList = someList.stream().limit(limit).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Let's say, `limit = 1000000` and `someList.size() = 99999`.

Now, will java be intelligent enough to understand that the list size is lesser than the limit?
Or will it go over each number in the list blindly until it reaches the end of the list or hits the limit?

Comment: `Stream#limit` isn't a terminal operation, so nothing will be executed regardless. Your code also won't compile, as `Stream#limit` does not return a `List`.

Comment: By the way `limit` is a cheap operation. I wouldn't be worried about whether it will be optimized out if the limit is more than the list's size

Comment: Looking at the source code, I think the answer is no.

Comment: @shmosel because the code doesn't compile, you mean?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt No, I'm assuming OP meant to do `.collect(toList())`.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long))? If it was unclear, then how?

Comment: @GBlodgett Will the limit operation be cheap even if the size of the list is in hundreds of thousands?

Comment: @OP, if you keep changing the question then answer meaning will go wrong, either mention changes by EDIT1 , EDIT2....etc.

Comment: Java will not be able to identify the size as stream operations are lazily executed, so the output will limit the size to `max`.

Comment: @CommonMan Thanks. Question is still the same, I just edited it to make it more clear

Comment: It's possible that it's optimized or will be in the future -- the list can return a Stream that knows the size and optimizes limit(), maybe using a SIZED spliterator -- but it's probably not.  It probably shouldn't matter to you, but If it matters to you then you should check the size yourself instead of relying on hidden details of the current implementation.

Comment: I doubt Java optimizes it (or actually can), because intermediate operations have no need to know which kind of underlying structure is currently providing their inputs.

Comment: In the beginning of the question, your asking about “the limit value is less than the size of the list”, at the end, it’s suddenly “the list size is lesser than the limit”. Further, it’s unclear, what kind of optimization you’re talking about. When you request a result list via `collect(Collectors.toList())`. There is nothing that what entitle the implementation to “not execute this code”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not optimize the execution (even in JDK 11).

Let's try the simplest terminal operation (`count`):

```
var someList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var limit = 10_000;
System.out.println(someList
        .stream()
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .limit(limit)
        .count());
```

The program will print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

So, it had to traverse the whole stream to find out an exact size.

Comment: so, it will return the full size of actual list, that's what i said.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov such an optimization would be more than possible, but most probably useless, since all you care in such a case is limiting an existing collection, without other intermediate operations, as such this is easily achieved with `size` and `subList` for example.

Comment: @Eugene I don’t think that this would be useless. After all, the optimization for `count()` on a `SIZED` stream was considered worth adding in Java 9. So why shouldn’t the same consideration apply to a stream with a limit? It’s just that the current implementation is incapable of keeping the `SIZED` characteristic. In my own implementation, it is. Which is very useful for operation like `toArray`.

Comment: @Eugene @Holger is right. `list.stream().limit().toArray()` would be more efficient if the exact size was known.

Comment: You should probably clarify what kind of optimization you're addressing, as it's not very clear from the question. My interpretation was that `limit()` could be a no-op given a SIZED stream, which this doesn't really disprove.

Answer (score 1):

`stream().limit(5)` is not terminal operation so you cannot limit the list thinking that i have done `limit()` and it will store the limited value in `limitedlist`. Even if you use `collect()` you still cannot achive to limit the list and store it in `limitedlist` as the type mismatch will occur.

You need to use `.collect()` as terminal operation and then use `Collectors.toList()` to add it to `limitedlist` , do not try to print it in the same line as it will throw error saying **type mismatch**.

stream operations are lazily executed so Java wont be able to throw error as it don't know the limit of your list, so if the limit size exceeds the actual size of list, then it will return the **maximum** size with all elements.

```
List<Long> someList = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L);
    List<Long> limitedList = someList.stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(long aa:limitedList)
    {
        System.out.println(aa);
    }
```

**case 2:** [ If the `limit` operation size exceeds the actual size of `somelist`. ]

```
List<Long> someList = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L);
        List<Long> limitedList = someList.stream().limit(7).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(long aa:limitedList)
        {
            System.out.println(aa);
        }
```

**Output**: The result will be the whole `somelist` elements.

**PS:** **Stream is not a data structure and stream operations are lazily executed.**

Comment: That was my intention. Somehow missed adding .collect(Collectors.toList() while typing it out here. Please try to understand the question and the intention behind it

Comment: I already trying top understand the situation and it seems Java cannot optimize it, It will return the max size in case if the limit happens to be larger than actual list size.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s try it out. Here’s a version of your code where the total size of your list is less than the limit (as your title says):

```
    List<Long> someList = Arrays.asList(7L, 2L, 11L, 5L);
    int limit = 6;
    List<Long> limitedList = someList.stream().skip(limit).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(limitedList);
```

The output is:

> [7, 2, 11, 5]

So the code does execute. Limiting the stream to 6 elements only sets a max. The stream is happy to execute with fewer elements if fewer are available from the list. So there isn’t really anything to optimize.

You may want to remember that streams execute lazily: elements are pulled from the terminal operation (here `toList`), typically until there aren’t any more elements. So `toList` requests elements from `limit`. `limit` will keep giving elements until *either* the limit (6)  is reached *or* it cannot get any more elements from the stream (the list is exhausted). It has to. If we imagine that it didn’t go over all elements, it would not be able to produce the correct result.

The lazy execution is also one reason why the comments said that your stream would not execute. In the first version of the question you didn’t have a terminal operation (like `collect(Collectors.toList());`), so no elements would ever be pulled from `limit` (you might call that optimization?) You have added a terminal operation now.

You might have had `skip` in mind? Let’s try to change the middle code line in the above:

```
    List<Long> limitedList = someList.stream().skip(6).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> []

Here `toList` requests elements from `skip`. `skip` first tries to get 6 elements from the list. After 4 the list is exhausted. At this point `skip` tells `toList` that there are no more elements, so `toList` returns an empty list. Again there isn’t really anything to optimize.